# Find the last occurrence of char in a string

Tags: string, delphi, delphi-2007

Does there exist any RTL Delphi function to determine the position of the last occurrence of a char in a string?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

try the [`LastDelimiter`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.LastDelimiter) function which is part of the SysUtils unit.

Comment: System.SysUtils.TStringHelper.LastIndexOf could also be handy when you want a string instead of a character.

Answer (score 22):

RRUZ answered the actual question (he gave you a RTL function).

Still, I cannot quite resist giving a simple code snippet that does what you want:

```
function LastCharPos(const S: string; const Chr: char): integer;
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  result := 0;
  for i := length(S) downto 1 do
    if S[i] = Chr then
      Exit(i);
end;
```

Since this does exactly what you want and offer no other features, it is far more compact (especially when we use the `Exit(Result)` syntax of Delphi 2009 and later) and probably slightly faster. In Delphi 2007, however, you have to do

```
function LastCharPos(const S: string; const Chr: char): integer;
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  result := 0;
  for i := length(S) downto 1 do
    if S[i] = Chr then
    begin
      result := i;
      break; // or Exit; if you prefer that
    end;
end;
```

Answer (score 12):

Use [`StrRScan`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/SysUtils.StrRScan) or [`AnsiStrRScan`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/SysUtils.AnsiStrRScan), both in the *SysUtils* unit. The latter, despite its name, works on Unicode characters in the Delphi versions where `string` is `UnicodeString`. (If you still need the "real" Ansi version, use the *AnsiStrings* unit.)

These functions search for exactly one character, whereas `LastDelimiter` searches for any of several characters from the given list of possibilities — think of `StrRScan` as `LastDelimiter` optimized for a one-character `Delimiters` argument.

Answer (score 4):

The best cross-platform solution is [TStringHelper.LastIndexOf](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.TStringHelper.LastIndexOf), it exists since Delphi XE4.

Note, that this function is 0-based.

Answer (score 1):

And here's my contribution for finding the position of the nth occurrence of a substring within a string.

```
function GetPositionOfNthOccurence(sSubStr, sStr: string; iNth: integer): integer;
var
  sTempStr: string;
  iIteration: integer;
  iTempPos: integer;
  iTempResult: integer;
begin
  result := 0;

  // validate input parameters
  if ((iNth < 1) or (sSubStr = '') or (sStr = '')) then exit;

  // evaluate
  iIteration := 0;
  iTempResult := 0;
  sTempStr := sStr;
  while (iIteration < iNth) do
  begin
    iTempPos := Pos(sSubStr, sTempStr);
    if (iTempPos = 0) then exit;
    iTempResult := iTempResult + iTempPos;
    sTempStr := Copy(sStr, iTempResult + 1, Length(sStr) - iTempResult);
    inc(iIteration);
  end;
  result := iTempResult;
end;
```

Comment: very good, because with this code also is possible determine quantity of occurences of a substring in a string. This solved a trouble to me now! thank you by your contribution.